# fill array with textbox text in a different thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am new to vb.net and multithreading. I'm trying to populate an array located in a module with all the line in textbox which is in a different thread.

Start a new thread>call Extract_All_0>fill BaseArray> run the remaining code.

```
    Imports System.Threading

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button35_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button35.Click

            'Call Extract_All_0
            TextBox19.ResetText
            Dim Thread_Extract_All As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOfExtract_All_0)

            Thread_Extract_All.IsBackground = True
            Thread_Extract_All.Start()

        End Sub

    End Class


   Option Explicit On


Imports VBScript_RegExp_55

Module ExtractAll

    Dim BaseToResult()
    Dim BaseArray()
    Dim Result_array(0) As String

    Sub Extract_All_0()

        Dim ResultVal As String = vbNullString


        Dim Regex As RegExp
        Dim Matches As MatchCollection
        Dim Match As Match

        Dim SearchPattern

        Dim Q As Long, w As Long, e As Long, r As Long, i As Long

        Dim lastRow As Long



        On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLER


        If Form1.TextBox21.Text <> vbNullString Then
            ReDim BaseArray(Form1.TextBox21.Lines.Count - 1)
            BaseArray = Form1.TextBox21.Lines

        Else
            MsgBox("No source data provided. Provide source data and try again.", vbCritical, "Error Manager")
            GoTo exit1
        End If


        If Form1.TextBox20.Text <> vbNullString Then
            Call Loadpatterns_Searchwhat_EA()
        Else
            MsgBox("Patterns not provided. Provide patterns and try again.", vbCritical, "Error Manager")
            GoTo exit1
        End If

        Form1.CheckBox6.Enabled = False
        Form1.CheckBox5.Enabled = False
        Form1.Button35.Enabled = False

        With Regex
                    .IgnoreCase = true
                    .Global = True
                    .Multiline = True
                End With


        On Error Resume Next


            ReDim Result_array(UBound(BaseArray))


        Regex = New RegExp

        For Q = LBound(BaseArray, 1) To UBound(BaseArray, 1)

            For w = LBound(BaseToResult) To UBound(BaseToResult)

                SearchPattern = BaseToResult(w)

                regex.Pattern = SearchPattern

                If Regex.Test(BaseArray(Q)) Then
                    Matches = Regex.Execute(BaseArray(Q))

                    For Each Match In Matches
                        If ResultVal = vbNullString Then
                            ResultVal = Match.Value
                        Else
                            ResultVal = ResultVal & vbTab & Match.Value
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

            Next w

            ResultVal = vbNullString

        Next Q

                   Form1.TextBox19.Text = Join(Result_array, vbNewLine)



        MsgBox("Extraction Complete", vbInformation, "ADMT")

        Exit Sub

    ERR_HANDLER:

        End Sub

    End Module
```

Any help is very much appreciated. thanks..

Comment: Controls can only be accessed from the thread that they were created on. Either put all the data you need in a class that you pass to the thread, or you have to [**invoke**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201701290149593551353) (modifying a control will require you to invoke).

Comment: thanks.. it worked for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear and I will try and fill in from what I could gather might be your problem??

Change "Sub Extract_All_0()" to "Sub Extract_All_0(strText As String)

Within the method -

```
If Form1.TextBox21.Text <> vbNullString Then
        ReDim BaseArray(Form1.TextBox21.Lines.Count - 1)
''''  Can't read the the lines from the textbox evne when it contains text.
        strText= Form1.TextBox21.Linesenter code here
```

Then in button35 -

```
TextBox19.Text = Extract_All_0(strText)
```

Looks sloppy but it is difficult to figure out what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: thanks Andre for your help. I have updated the code and I'll try to fill you in about what i'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to use multithreading to run the sub procedure. now since the form and the procedure will be run on  two different threads, I'm not able to fill the base array with values. when the user hits the run button on  the form a new thread is supposed to be created and the Extract_all_0 procedure should run in it and post completion the result should be updated to the other textbox in the form.